# how to get value of div, label, textbox without button click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of tutors which is dynamically append on **label**, **textbox**.

i want is when i load the page it gives me the value of **label, textbox** in alert box without clicking the button.

**following is my code:**

**index.html**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label class="label label-info" for="">Email</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <p id="txtemail"></p>
                                        <input id="txtemails" type="text" disabled>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label class="label label-info" for="">Category</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><div id="category"></div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label class="label label-info" for="">Preferred Location</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><label id="location" for=""></label></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label class="label label-info" for="">Preferred Board</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><label id="board" for=""></label></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label class="label label-info" for="">Preferred Class</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><label id="classes" for=""></label></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label class="label label-info" for="">Preferred Subject</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><label id="subjects" for=""></label></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

**tutor-details.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/tutor-details.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data)
        {
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(result, function(key, value){
                $.each(value, function(k, v){
                    if (k === 'image_path') {
                        $('#tutImg').attr("src",v.slice(3));
                    }
                    if (k === 'name') {
                        $('#name').append(v);
                    }
                    if (k === 'contact_number') {
                        $('#contact').append(v);
                    }
                    if (k === 'about') {
                        $('#about').append(v);
                    }
                    if (k === 'email') {
                        $('#email').append(v);
                    }
                    if (k === 'email') {
                        $('#txtemail').append(v);
                        $('#txtemails').val(v);
                    }
                    if (k === 'location') {
                        $('#location').append(v);
                    }
                    if (k === 'board') {
                        $('#board').append(v);
                    }
                    if (k === 'class') {
                        $('#classes').append(v);
                    }
                    if (k === 'subject') {
                        $('#subject').append(v);
                    }
                    if (k === 'tutor_category') {
                        if (v === "Diamond") {
                        $('#category').append(v);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Which label, which textbox?

Comment: I'm not seeing any notion of a button anywhere that you wish to avoid